# CKEditor script does not work on heavy HTML page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I am trying to use the [CKEditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) gem with Rails 4.0.3. I have setup everything according to the docs, but it does not work.

I have a main project with a page which contains many html elements. In this page CKEditor does not work, and does not give any errors or warnings, neither on server side nor on client side (Javascript).

But when I created a test project, and applied the same settings, it worked!

After a lot of struggling, I finally came to this conclusion:

CKEditor inserts a bit of Javascript after the textarea which is supposed to converted. Here is the code:

```
//<![CDATA[
    if (typeof CKEDITOR != 'undefined') { CKEDITOR.replace('article_body'); }
//]]>
```

I think the problem is that, on the page with many html elements, the code above is run before the DOM is completey loaded, so it has no effect. But on the other page the DOM loads quickly and the code is run in time.

One thing that validates my assumption is that if I run the Javascript code above in the Chrome Developer tools' console, when the page has been completely loaded, it does work.

I don't know if I am right or not, but supposing I am right, how can I force the code above to run when the DOM is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It is because I moved the

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

line to the end of the file, before the closing body tag. This line:

```
//<![CDATA[
    if (typeof CKEDITOR != 'undefined') { CKEDITOR.replace('article_body'); }
//]]>
```

was executed before any other Javascript files were loaded, so it did nothing.

And the solution:

One way is to move the `stylesheet_link_tag` line to top of the file (which I don't like).

Another way is to add a CSS class named `ckeditor` to the textarea which you want to be converted. For example:

```
= form_for @article do |f|
    = f.text_area :body, class: "ckeditor"
```

This will tell CKEditor to convert that textarea to a WYSIWYG editor.